# Xcode build hangs when there are more than 3 data model entities

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I can't build Xcode projects (objc or Swift) when there are more than 3 entities defined in my data model (xcdatamodeld). When there are 3 or fewer entities it builds just fine, add one more and it hangs.

I've been able to reproduce this with a brand new project in either objc or Swift (including core data) so I'm confident it's not an issue with my project. Screenshot below:

[image: New project with 4 data model entities]

Looking at the report navigator I can see it's stuck on the data model compilation step, though there doesn't appear to be anything wrong.

[image: Compiler output]

Running Xcode Version 7.0.1 (7A1001) & OS X 10.11 (15A284) El Capitan

Comment: Your data model in Project Navigator is named Blah and yet your target is attempting to build a data model named Foo...

Comment: Thanks @andrewbuilder, my apologies the screenshots are actually from  two different projects. The first was objc (Blah) and the second was Swift (Foo). I was just testing both to see if the problem existed regardless of language – which it does.

Comment: @andrewbuilder I've updated the screenshot to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version of El Capitan – OS X 10.11.1 (15B42) resolved the issue. Project now builds as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same error - Xcode was hanging while trying to compile the core data model in our app - rebooting, of all the things, fixed it for me.

Comment: Weird. What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: Latest at the time of writing mate, 7.1 I believe

Comment: You've got to be *kidding me*! I've been having the same problem for two weeks now, not once did I consider rebooting. I did re-install Xcode 7, tried downloading older Xcode (6), nothing worked... but a plain reboot did. Thanks @crafterm!